# Allow multiple login methods in web2py

Tags: python, oauth, web2py

I am building an application using web2py and I am not sure how I can enable multiple authentication methods at the same time. For example I would like to use both Google and Facebook OAuth and also allow the user to sign up using the default web2py authentication system. 
Right now I have implemented the Google OAuth and it works but I am not able to add other methods.

I think the main problem is this line of code where i define the authentication "system" for web2py. I tried reading the book but couldn't really find something helpful.

```
auth.settings.login_form=googleAccount()
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement multiple login system, you need different urls for different login in case of OAuth 2.0:

Example:

1. For Google use /app/user/login/google
2. For Facebook user /app/user/login/facebook

Sample Code:

```
def user():
from facebook_google_login import *
if request.args(0) == 'login':
    if request.args(1) == 'facebook':
        facebook_login = FaceBookAccount(db=db)
        facebook_login.login_url(URL( 'AppName','default','user', args=['login','facebook']))
        auth.settings.login_form=facebook_login
    elif request.args(1) == 'google':
        google_login = GoogleAccount(globals())
        google_login.login_url(URL('AppName','default','user', args=['login','google']))
        auth.settings.login_form=google_login
```